# Pandas merge by keep first element of a column and last of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with different value and ID that can be in common.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr2'],
                    'B': [700,750,800,850,900,200],
                    'C': [750,800,850,900,950,250],
                    'D':['id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1','id_2']})
```

What I'm trying to do is to keep lowest element of B, higher of C for identical value A and D

Output should look :

```
    A    B    C    D
0  chr1 700  950   id_1
1  chr2 200  250   id_2
```

I tried to use

```
groupby('D').agg(['first', 'last'])
```

But it's not what I want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary by columns names and aggregate functions:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('D', as_index=False)
         .agg({'A':'first', 'B':'first', 'C':'last'})
         [['A','B','C','D']])
print (df1)
      A    B    C     D
0  chr1  700  950  id_1
1  chr2  200  250  id_2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dict` passed the name and function inside the `agg`

```
df.groupby(['A','D'],as_index=False).agg({'B':'first','C':'last'}).reindex(columns=df.columns)
      A    B    C     D
0  chr1  700  950  id_1
1  chr2  200  250  id_2
```